# EntityKey is not defined error

Tags: breeze

I develop an asp.net mvc solution with breeze/durandal.

I would like to execute the following code:

```
var entityKey = new EntityKey(entityNames.transport, transportId);
var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey).expand("Sender.Country");
```

And I got the following error:

`EntityKey is not defined`

I don't know why.

I can execute code below:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Transports')
                       .where('id', 'eq', transportId)
                       .expand('Sender.Country')
                       .orderBy(orderBy.transport);

return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(fetchSucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
```

So breeze seems correctly installed.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be breeze.EntityKey, but to make it easier to use we often assign it to a shorter name before using it. i.e.

```
var EntityKey = breeze.EntityKey;
```

You've obviously done something similar for EntityQuery.